# Resource URL problem

Tags: civicrm.settings.php, resource-urls

I'm having some problems with the CiviCRM Resource URL setting that I can't get my head around. Set as `[civicrm.root]/` the System Status screen displays the error 'The Resource URL is not set correctly'. Set as `[cms.root]/sites/all/modules/civicrm/` everything seems to work fine ([until I try to upgrade](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/35178/unable-to-upgrade-from-version-5-22-1)). But surely both should resolve to the same place?

In the File System Paths section of civicrm.settings.php I have the following:

```
$civicrm_root = '/var/sites/c/beta.example.net/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm';
if (!defined('CIVICRM_TEMPLATE_COMPILEDIR')) {
  define( 'CIVICRM_TEMPLATE_COMPILEDIR', '/var/sites/c/beta.example.net/public_html/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/');
}
```

And in the Site URLs section I have:

```
if (!defined('CIVICRM_UF_BASEURL')) {
  define( 'CIVICRM_UF_BASEURL'      , 'https://example.net/');
}
```

Trying to load the with the `[civicrm.root]/` setting results in a load of javascript errors, of which the following is an example:

```
[Error] Failed to load resource: The request timed out. (logo_sm.png, line 0) https://var/sites/c/beta.example.net/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/i/logo_sm.png
```

That looks as though $civicrm_root is set incorrectly, but it seems to be right in accordance with the examples given in the comments. What am I missing?

**Edit:** If I go to the CiviCRM Resources URLs page and click on ? I see the variables listed as:

```
[cms.root]  https://example.net/
[civicrm.root]  https://example.net//var/sites/c/beta.example.net/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/
[civicrm.files] https://example.net/sites/default/files/civicrm/
```

But if I got to the Directories page and do the same, I see

```
[cms.root]  /var/sites/j/example.net/public_html
[civicrm.root]  /var/sites/c/beta.example.net/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm
[civicrm.files] /var/sites/c/beta.example.net/public_html/sites/default/files/civicrm
```

Where are these getting calculated from that means they're producing different results? Particularly that random one with the /j/ in the middle, which I've never seen before anywhere!

Comment: I had a similar problem after upgrading to 5.23.4 from 5.20.0. Mine was due to cron calling drush with a -r parameter which was a symbolic link to the drupal directory, equivalent but not identical to the path used to specify $civicrm_root. This used to work, but now caused links in emails to have a path like https://example.com/drupal//var/www/clients/client1/web1/web/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/extern/url.php. After changing the drush -r parameter to /var/www/clients/client1/web1/web/drupal my problem was resolved. Check for inconsistent use of symbolic links in all resource paths/urls.

Comment: What is your drupal path set in apache or nginx config?

Comment: @PradeepNayak How do I find that out? Drupal is installed at /var/sites/example.net/public_html/ but I'm on shared hosting, so I don't have access to anything above /var/sites/example.net/.

Comment: @BobS Any hints on where to start looking? I'm not using drush. I don't have any custom code, and find . -type l -ls returns nothing.

Comment: Can you go to CiviCRM directories page and click on '?' and paste all the variables

Comment: @PradeepNayak Huh. Well that's weird. I've updated the question. And also amended some of the other paths I'd given. As far as I'd ever been aware, my site was in /var/sites/c/beta.example.net/public_html/, so I'd been contracting that to /var/sites/example.net/public_html/ for simplicity. But one of those variables shows /var/sites/j/example.net/public_html/. I've no idea where it's coming from, but I guess that's the problem! I originally built the site on beta.example.net, and my host told me they couldn't update the account, so example.net is support to just alias to beta.example.net.

Comment: I just changed my civicrm.root and CIVICRM_TEMPLATE_COMPILEDIR to use a linked path and got similar results to yours. Try running "realpath /var/sites/c/beta.example.net/public_html". If you see anything other than what you expect, try using that resulting path in your settings file and Directories page instead.

Comment: @BobS My host doesn't appear to allow me to run realpath. Thanks a lot though. Pradeep's solution has fixed the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your civicrm.setting.php update the $civicrm_root and template_c path to use `/var/sites/j/example.net/public_html` instead of `/var/sites/c/beta.example.net/public_html/`

Thanks

Pradeep

Comment: I don't really understand it, but it works. Thanks!