# Suggestions re 5.23.0 upgrade fail

Tags: upgrade

I'm trying to upgrade a site that had not been upgraded since 4.7.31. I tried to go directly to 5.44 but the database upgrade wouldn't run - it just gave me "CiviCRM Upgrade Tasks Retry Skip []" with nothing in the task list.

To resolve this I started upgrading more gradually and was able to get successfully to 5.22.1. But I can't get beyond that.  The next version is 5.23.0. Trying to upgrade 5.22.1->5.23.0 gives me the same as the original issue - empty task list at civicrm/upgrade.php "CiviCRM Upgrade Tasks Retry Skip []"

There are no errors in ConfigAndLog and no errors in the error log on the website.  Is there somewhere else I should look to see error messages?

The only other thing that I've noticed is that if I run &directoryCleanup=1 I get some error messages such as "Smarty error: the $compile_dir '/home/customer/www/XXXXX/public_html/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_US/' does not exist, or is not a directory. in Smarty->trigger_error() (line 1100 of /home/customer/www/XXXXX/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/Smarty/Smarty.class.php)."

The directory definitely does exist. I didn't see anything obviously wrong with the permissions, but this seems like it might be a permissions error since the directory is definitely there.

Any suggestions for next steps would be appreciated.

Comment: I've got a similar but different upgrade issue. Only some sections have failed but again errors mention smarty and templates and directories. Hmm. https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/41101/out-of-memory-and-civi-errors-relating-to-templates-following-upgrade-from-5-35

Comment: Solved. This was related to https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/35178/unable-to-upgrade-from-version-5-22-1

My [civicrm.root] and [civicrm.files] were not right, and not consistent with  
[cms.root].  (The clue to this was ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED errors in console on the stuck upgrade page.) 

I fixed $civicrm_root  and CIVICRM_TEMPLATE_COMPILEDIR in civicrm.settings.php and then ran 5.22.1 -> 5.23.0 smoothly. Hurray!

I think this happened when a new host migrated our site for us. It's curious that it didn't impact us before.

I will try to get the rest of the way later.